# Google maps iOS sdk get tapped overlay coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

i'm working with Google maps iOS sdk. 
i want to get the coordinates of the touched point when user taps an overlay.

there is this delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
```

but it's not called when you tap an overlay or a marker.

can i call it programmatically (but coordinate parameter is missing-that's what i want..)?
or get location from this:

```
- (void) mapView: (GMSMapView *) mapView  didTapOverlay: (GMSOverlay *) overlay
```

any suggestion's precious!

thanks!

Comment: Did you find any solution? It's crazy the developers didn't create a `didTapAtCoordinate` for overlays

Comment: take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/40583753/5559741

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE 6/2/15

Just staple a UITapGestureRecognizer onto the map and then extract the coordinate from the touch point. Your didTapAtCoordinate and didTapAtOverlay will continue to fire as before.

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *touchTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTouchTap:)];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:touchTap];

-(void)tapTouchTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)touchGesture
{
  CGPoint point = [touchGesture locationInView:self.view];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [self.mapView.projection coordinateForPoint:point];
  NSLog(@"%f %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
}
```

ORIGINAL POST

You are likely missing two snippets of code.
Adopt the GMSMapViewDelegate in your header file:

```
@interface Map : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

You also need to set the delegate in your viewDidLoad:

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

Now this should fire for you:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    NSLog(@"You tapped at %f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Comment: This is correct but this method will not fire on an overlay tap.  OP likely has this setup but is searching for a way to fire on an overlay tap as well to get geocoords of overlay tap location.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get the position of the marker, there is a position property

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = marker.position;
```

When this delegate method gets called

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
```

its for screen taps that have no markers or overlays from my expierience.

GMSOverlay is a bit different because its a super class to a GMSMarker. You just need to subclass GMSOverlay for your custom overlays and add a position property. When you create the overlay, say in didTapAtCoordinate, you can assign the position (GPS coord) in there.

Comment: yes, i can get marker position, but i'm interested in getting the position of GMSPolygon and GMSPolyline where they're tapped. the shape already exists when user taps on it. 
substantially, i want to zoom at that position at the tap event.
(yes, i wasn't so explanatory..)
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the circle not tappable (default behaviour) and catch all the clicks on the map with the `didTapAtCoordinate` delegate.

Then when this event is triggered you could loop over all your circles to check if the user tapped inside one of the circles or outside.

Answer (score 1):

> self.mapview.settings.consumesGesturesInView = NO;

Add this line in viewdidload or after allocating.

And then implement this delegate method.

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    NSLog(@"%g",coordinate);
}


- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapOverlay:(GMSOverlay *)overlay
{

    GMSCircle *circle=(GMSCircle *)overlay;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchCoOrdinate= circle.position;
    NSLog(@"%g",touchCoOrdinate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can't get the didTapAtCoordinateMethod to fire for an overlay tap.  However I did find a slightly dirty workaround.

Using an overlay to draw polylines, we need a way to recognize where a polyline was tapped.  So when drawing polylines we can build them like this.

```
    //draw line
    GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    polyline.tappable = TRUE;
    polyline.map = self.googleMapView;
    polyline.title = routestring;
```

Where routestring is a built string from

```
routestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",lat,lng,[annnotationobject objectForKey:@"linkId"]];
```

And lat and lng are string values of our coordinates.  The last part is an ID for the polyline.

The routestring is storing the coordinates and an ID separated by '/' so that we can use component path of string to look them up later.  This is assigned to the polylines title.

Now when the overlay is tapped:

```
-(void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapOverlay:(GMSOverlay *)overlay{

NSString *path = overlay.title;

//Finding componentpaths of string
NSArray *pathparts = [path pathComponents];
NSString *lat = [pathparts objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lng = [pathparts objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *linkID = [pathparts objectAtIndex:2];

//Here we are building a marker to place near the users tap location on the polyline.
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([lat doubleValue],[lng doubleValue])];
marker.title = overlay.title;
marker.snippet = @"ROUTE DATA";
marker.map = self.googleMapView;

//This will popup a marker window
[self.googleMapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
```

}

We can use component paths of the string we built(separated by "/")to get the latitude and longitude coordinates from the polyline.  Then assign them a marker to popup information on the overlay item.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UITapGestureRecognizer and override its touchesEnded to retrieve the touch point, than retrieve the coordinate with GMSMapView's coordinateForPoint.

Subclass UITapGestureRecognizer and add it to your mapView:

```
self.touchTap = [[TouchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTouchTap)];
self.touchTap.mapView = self.mapView;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.touchTap];
```

TouchDownGestureRecognizer.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>    

@interface TouchGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer
@property  GMSMapView       *mapView;
@end
```

TouchDownGestureRecognizer.m:

```
#import "TouchGestureRecognizer.h"
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@implementation TouchGestureRecognizer

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

  UITouch *touch = touches.allObjects[0];
  CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.mapView];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [self.mapView.projection coordinateForPoint:point];
  NSLog(@"%f %f", coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
}

@end
```