# Polyline Tap in Google Maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I wonder if there is a tap listener for polylines drawn in Google Map. The marker's tap is this:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

        return false
    }
```

Is there any equivalent function for polylines? I believe in Google Maps version 3 for web, you have the ability to add event listener for polylines like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(elines[i], 'click', function()
        {
            lineClick(this);
        });

Thanks!
```

Is this also possible in ios/swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isTappable` property of GMSPolyline.

> isTappable
>
> If this overlay should cause tap notifications.

```
polyline.isTappable = true
```

Whenever the polyline is tapped, the GMSMapViewDelegate method didTapOverlay is called

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
        //Write your code here
    }
```

For further information refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#a3a2bf2ff4481528f931183cb364c0f4b

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you know how do I get the lat and long (geo location) of that overlay?

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857744/google-maps-ios-sdk-get-tapped-overlay-coordinates to get the coordinate of the tapped location.