# Get LAT and LONG from tapped overlay in Google Maps

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

When a user taps an overlay, the following code is triggered:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {


    }
```

I wonder if we can extract the exact LAT and LONG coordinates of the overlay that has been tapped?

Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 3):

To solve this we need the 2 methods together,
So I combined them in a way I hope it will help in this issue:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
    print(overlay)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print(coordinate)

    for polyline in polylines {
        if GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPath(coordinate, polyline.path!, true) {
            self.mapView(mapView, didTap: polyline)
        }
    }
    for polygon in polygons {
        if GMSGeometryContainsLocation(coordinate, polygon.path!, true) {
            self.mapView(mapView, didTap: polygon)
        }
    }
}
```

if the user clicked at `coordinate` we will deal with this, Then check if this `coordinate` is contained in any `Polyline` or `Polygon` we had defined before, So we `fire` the event `didTap overlay` for that `overlay`.

**Make sure to make `polylines` and `polygons` `isTappable = false`**

*And but in mind this event will be fired for every `overlay` tapped even though if they are `overlaped`, You can put `return` when the `if` success to take the first `overlay` only*

Comment: Work for me. However  i think that self.mapView(mapView, didTap: polyline) is not necesary. Goog answer. @wajeeh

Answer (score 2):

You can use didTapAt delegate method for the same.

@wajih, for you did the method didTapAt was called when you tap on landmark names or titles? For me it's not getting called.
For my case the landmark title is above the polygon and the didTapAt method is not getting called, but if i set tappable to true then didTap(overlay) is called perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the exact coordinates wherever you tapped whether on Overlay or not, then there is another delegate of `GMSMapViewDelegate` which is called whenever we tap on `GoogleMaps`. In this delegate you can get the exact coordinates where you tapped on map irrespective of tapping on an overlay.

> **Swift 3.0**

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        print(coordinate.latitude)
        print(coordinate.longitude)
    }
```

If you want to get the coordinate only on tapping marker, then use this delegate method

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        print(marker.position.latitude)
        print(marker.position.longitude)
        return true
    }
```

Make sure to make your overlay as non-tappable

```
overlay.isTappable = false
```

For reference see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#a9f226252840c79a996df402da9eec235)

Comment: I have a polyline drawn in the map and I need to have it tappable. So I need `overlay.isTappable = true`.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo I guess there is no method in `GoogleMapsSDK` that can give you exact coordinates on tapping overlay. You can only receive an event that you tapped an overlay, but will not get coordinates on tapping overlay as `GMSOverlay` class has no coordinate options.

Comment: There should be another way. Is there any possibility to have `didTapAt` while also listening for overlay tap?

Comment: I don't think so. If you have made your `overlay` as tappable `true` then `didTapAt` is never called.

Comment: `didTapAt` is never called whenever you tap on `overlay`. It will be called when you tap outside the `overlay`

Comment: @JaysonTamayo Did you find any solution. I guess the thing which I mentioned is true currently.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo maybe the new answer will help you