# When a user taps an overlay, the following code is triggered:

Tags: ios, swift

I wonder if we can extract the exact `LAT` and `LONG` coordinates of the overlay that has been tapped?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {


}
```

I want to get the exact coordinates, but I cannot get the coordinates when tapping on the overlay.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get LAT and LONG from tapped overlay in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977363/get-lat-and-long-from-tapped-overlay-in-google-maps)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
    print(overlay)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    print(coordinate)

    for polyline in polylines {
        if GMSGeometryIsLocationOnPath(coordinate, polyline.path!, true) {
            self.mapView(mapView, didTap: polyline)
        }
    }
    for polygon in polygons {
        if GMSGeometryContainsLocation(coordinate, polygon.path!, true) {
            self.mapView(mapView, didTap: polygon)
        }
    }
}
```

Similar question was asked. And this is an answer from older thread. [Get LAT and LONG from tapped overlay in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39977363/get-lat-and-long-from-tapped-overlay-in-google-maps)